# Protected Word 2007 Document not working

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have an annoying problem that I've never had before.  I've created forms within Word 2003 many years back and protected the document so that users can only complete the fields.

However, I'm having some annoying issues with Word 2007.  I've created a document with a cover page, TOC and the rest of the document.  But even after protecting the document and selecting "Filling in forms" only.  I can select and type within the first line of the cover page and at the end of the TOC.

Entering Design Mode, shows "CoverPage" tags and "Table of Contents" tags in the parts I can also edit, I have no idea how to get around this problem and have searched high and low.

If anyone can help me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a _programming_ Q&A. Using Microsoft Word is not programming. Try your luck over at http://superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Dexter, Are you sure there are no sections that have editing exceptions (under editing restrictions).